# Dynamic Pivot Table for status on particular days in SQL

Tags: sql, dynamic, pivot

I've seen parts of it done but trying to get it all in one thing.  Creating a single output table from two seperate ones.

```
tblMeetingTime one
-----------------
MeetingID   GroupID    MeetingTime
1           21          11/5/2011 8:30
2           21          11/9/2011 14:30
3           21          11/15/2011 8:30
4           23          11/5/2011 13:00
.           .           .
.           .           .

tblPeople
------------------------
GroupID     PersonID
21          3463  
21          3563
23          3245
.           .

tblRecordAttendance
--------------------------------
MeetingID    PeronID      Status
1            3463         A
1            3563         NULL
2            3463         N
2            3563         N
.            .            .
```

If needed to I can redo some of the tables, but that is how the raw data is brought in.  I am hoping to have something like

```
 Person     11/5/2011 8:30 AM      11/9/2011 2:30 PM      ...      
 --------------------------------------------------- 
 3463        A                      N
 3563                               N
 .
 .
 .
```

I have a good idea of how to do it in straight C#, but it would take a good amount of opening, repulling and organizing the data and hoping to come up with some sort of SQL Pivot to do it all, particularly with new MeetingTimes being added for each group.

Thanks,

Wade

Comment: Why do you need to "repull" data to do it in C#? Grab all of the data that you need and process it. Since you don't have any definitive number of days across that you plan to display you're better off doing this processing in the front end anyway.

Comment: I would rather do all the data in SQL.  I don't want to do it in C# for performance reason and etc... but if I have to do it on the web page, I can.  Just trying to avoid and create a single pull via stored procedure or pull for a group to display or update the status if they attended the meeting.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server requires that all column values are pre-defined for the PIVOT operator.  The only way to do it in a SP would be to first query all the column values, then create a PIVOT command as a string and pass it to sp_executesql to get your answer.

I would suggest using SQL Server Reporting Services.  You can use the ReportViewer control in client-only mode and don't even need the server components installed.  Then, you can create a matrix report that calculates what you need.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671.aspx

Don't let MSDN scare you off.  It's really as simple as installing the control on your computer (and the Web server); Visual Studio will then have a report designer plug-in that opens whenever you open an RDLC file.  It also adds a "Report" option to the "Add New..." menu.

You could do it manually in C# as well.  You don't need to re-query.  Whether you leverage the ReportViewer control or do it yourself, you just pull the listing from the procedure as a big stack of person/meeting rows.  If you're using .NET 4, then LINQ to Objects will make it a snap to process in plain C# while building your HTML table.

Comment: Hi,  

Reporting services would not be good since I would have to do it more on the fly.  I am using .NET 3.5 and can't do the LINQ, so for other reasons I went an evil way of dynamically generating tables and tables and getting and storing the data that way.  Not the best but it seemed to be working.  Massive files and reads, but the asynchronous aspect is good enough with the unpredictable source data.

Thanks for the advice,

Wade